# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea

Всем привет.

Возникает ошибка :

```
   07-20 23:41:55.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.test.TestActivity
    at com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:110)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   07-20 23:41:56.013: ERROR/android.os.Debug(2268): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Возникает при переходе с одного Activity на другое

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  finish();
```

Оба Activity находятся в одном packagе com.example.test и прописаны в manifeste.
Но TestActivity использует стороннюю библиотеку, подключенную как module в IDEA Jetbrains

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне нужно сделать в IDEA , чтобы исправить эту ошибку ?

Answer (score 1):

Поставь птичку Android Private Libraries.
Это: project - properties - Java Build patch - Order and Export

Если ты конешно правельно подключил библиотеку. И директория с библиотекой должна называться libs (а не lib).

Comment: Вот я не могу найти в IDEA где находится "Java Build patch - Order and Export"

Answer (score 0):

```
TestActivity.class
```

зарегистрируй в манифесте

Comment: <activity _:name=".TestActivity.class"></activity> выделяет красным .TestActivity.class и тоже самое происходит, т.е. та же ошибка и вылетает приложение

Comment: Может поможет, но при компиляции вылетает такое сообщение android-validator: Suspicious module dependency My_project -> pdfviewer2.9.2: Android application module depends on other application module. Possibly, you should change type of module 'pdfviewer2.9.2' to 'Library' or change the dependency scope to 'Provided'. 
pdfviewer я подключаю как module. а в TestActivity есть взаимодействие с классами из этого module.

Comment: сложно по твоему описанию что-то сказать, может подключил не правильно либу, может путь не правильно указываешь...